# What happens to ICO tokens released to a wallet that does not support ERC20 tokens

Tags: blockchain, wallets, ico

If during a crowdsale you provide a wallet address that does not support ERC20 tokens will the Team send your tokens to a generated Ethereum address to be retrieved later with a private key and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

No, most of the ICOs give you several warnings before sending the money about using an address whose private key you do own.

If for some reason you still used an incorrect address, many ICO devs will allow you to contact them to let them know and find a solution BEFORE they distribute the tokens.

If they already assigned/distributed the tokens your money and tokens are probably lost.

Comment: Thanks for the response, This is for a friend and I'm sick about it because he invested in Power Ledger on my advise but he used a Bitcoin address from Blockchain.info wallet and Power Ledger sent him an email saying it was sent to an ethereum address that he doesn't control, how can he get the key to that address? How did they decide where to send it because that is not the address that he gave them?